# Change animation with click

Tags: animation, game-engine, keyframes, animation-nodes, blend4web

I am beginner and making an educational tutorial animation.

However I want my animation in such way that it should keep looping **indifinitely**  through a **specific set of frames** and advance to next set of frames only when clicked or arrow keys are hit.

Let me make it clear by example-

I made an animation having 200 frames.Now instead of playing it direct from start to end, I would like to-

1) Play frames 1 to 100 when I click. When frame 100 is reached, animation should loop back to frame 1 and play again to upto frame 100.
This should repeat until I make next click.

2) Now I click for second time, the animation should play from frame 101 t0 150 and keep repeating until next click.

3) On third click animation should play from 151 to 200 until clicked next.

[image: Below is the image representing those set of frames]

Please note that frames should continuously loop themselves until clicked **without time boundation.**

This can sound silly but but I need it. 
I am a beginner and have limited knowledge about blender and  will be grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: As far as I'm aware Animation Nodes is a procedural animation system, not an interactive framework. I don't think it can button presses or selection or any other "real time events" as input. How would you render such animation?

Comment: Wait, why did you tag your question as both animation nodes and Blend4web and game engine? How are you animating this? What addons are you using?

Comment: The structured animation you are talking about can be done. Just not in a way that is interactive as you described.

Comment: @OmarAhmad Yes sir,but how to do it. I am a beginner and wiil be very grateful  if you tell it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MohammadSaim Well, then please edit the question to explain in more details what you are trying to do.